# CSS fixed positioning/z-index in chrome extension

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, css-position, z-index

I'm building a Chrome extension that slides from right side of browser's window after clicking a yellow bar fixed to browser's right side. When I click on yellow bar, green and yellow bars will slide. The yellow one is correctly "on the top" of page- it covers page's content. Unfortunately green one after sliding is under some page's elements. For example on stackoverflow site, a green bar is under search window, ask question button and similar questions section. How can I fix it ?

manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version":         2,
"content_scripts":          [ {
    "js":       [ "injection.js", "jquery.js",  "jquery-ui.min.js"],
    "matches":  [   "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/*"
    ]
} ],
"description":              "Inject a complete, premade web page",
"name":                     "Inject whole web page",
"version":                  "1",
"web_accessible_resources": ["test.css", "jquery-ui.min.css"]
}
```

test.css

```
#intro_button {
background-color: yellow;
height : 100%;
width : 100px;
top: 0;
right: 0;
position : fixed;
cursor: pointer;    
}
#extension {
height: 100%;
width: 200px;
position: fixed;
right: -200px;
background-color: green;
}
```

injection.js

```
// Injecting button (div)
var divElement = document.createElement("DIV");
divElement.id = "intro_button";
divElement.style.right = "0px";
divElement.onclick = function () {
    if (this.style.right === "0px") {
        $(this).animate({ "right": "+=200" }, 800);
        $("#extension").animate({ "right": "+=200" }, 800);
    }
    else if (this.style.right === "200px") {
        $(this).animate({ "right": "-=200" }, 800);
        $("#extension").animate({ "right": "-=200" }, 800);
    }
}
var textnode = document.createTextNode("zzz");    
divElement.appendChild(textnode);
document.body.appendChild(divElement, document.body.firstChild);

// Injecting extenion (div)
var divExtension = document.createElement("DIV");
divExtension.id = "extension";
var textnode = document.createTextNode("yyy");
divExtension.appendChild(textnode);
document.body.insertBefore(divExtension, document.body.firstChild);

// Injecting CSS files
var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var link  = document.createElement('link');
link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
link.type = 'text/css';
link.href = chrome.extension.getURL('test.css');
head.appendChild(link);

var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var link  = document.createElement('link');
link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
link.type = 'text/css';
link.href = chrome.extension.getURL('jquery-ui.min.css');
head.appendChild(link);

// Injecting Jqueries
var s  = document.createElement('script');
s.src = "jquery.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);

var s  = document.createElement('script');
s.src = "jquery-ui.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why is this happening?

#### The element which is *incorrectly* layered is inserted before the body with [`.insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore):

```
document.body.insertBefore(divExtension, document.body.firstChild);
```

This is placing the element outside the `<body>` (before it) and is causing `z-index` issues with other `position: absolute` / `fixed` elements.

#### The element which is *correctly* layered is appended inside the body with [`.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

```
document.body.appendChild(divElement, document.body.firstChild);
```

This is placing the element **inside** `<body>` (where it should be) and *after all its other children*.

---

With natural z-layering, `absolute` / `fixed` elements **will be overlapped by similar elements which follow them**:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.red {
  background: red;
  left: 20px;
  top: 10px;
}
.green {
  background: green;
  left: 30px;
  top: 20px;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
  left: 40px;
  top: 30px;
}
.purple {
  background: purple;
  left: 50px;
  top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">Red is underneath all its siblings</div>
<div class="green">Green overlaps red</div>
<div class="blue">Blue overlaps green</div>
<div class="purple">Purple overlaps blue</div>
```

---

### The problem recreated

Note how the `.incorrect` div is placed before the body tag. It behaves the same way as the incorrectly inserted element in your example and is overlapped by the content div inside the `<body>`

```js
// Injecting button (div)
var divElement = document.createElement("DIV");
divElement.id = "intro_button";
var textnode = document.createTextNode("zzz");
divElement.appendChild(textnode);
document.body.appendChild(divElement, document.body.firstChild);

// Injecting extenion (div)
var divExtension = document.createElement("DIV");
divExtension.id = "extension";
var textnode = document.createTextNode("yyy");
divExtension.appendChild(textnode);
document.body.appendChild(divExtension, document.body.firstChild);

// Injecting CSS files
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.type = 'text/css';
link.href = chrome.extension.getURL('test.css');
head.appendChild(link);

var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.type = 'text/css';
link.href = chrome.extension.getURL('jquery-ui.min.css');
head.appendChild(link);

// Injecting Jqueries
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = "jquery.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);

var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = "jquery-ui.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
```

```css
.content {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 100px;
  background: #F00;
  position: absolute;
}
#intro_button {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#extension {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: green;
}
.incorrect {
  position: fixed;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="incorrect"></div>

<body>
  <div class="content">Content</div>
</body>
```

---

### How can we fix this?

You should use a large `z-index` value on the injected elements to absolutely ensure that they are always on top and...

#### Make sure both of the elements are inserted inside the body with `.appendChild`:

```
// Injecting button (div)
var divElement = document.createElement("DIV");
divElement.id = "intro_button";
divElement.style.right = "0px";
divElement.onclick = function () {
    if (this.style.right === "0px") {
        $(this).animate({ "right": "+=200" }, 800);
        $("#extension").animate({ "right": "+=200" }, 800);
    }
    else if (this.style.right === "200px") {
        $(this).animate({ "right": "-=200" }, 800);
        $("#extension").animate({ "right": "-=200" }, 800);
    }
}
var textnode = document.createTextNode("zzz");    
divElement.appendChild(textnode);
document.body.appendChild(divElement, document.body.firstChild);

// Injecting extenion (div)
var divExtension = document.createElement("DIV");
divExtension.id = "extension";
var textnode = document.createTextNode("yyy");
divExtension.appendChild(textnode);
document.body.appendChild(divExtension, document.body.firstChild);
// ## Changed to appendChild here ##

// Injecting CSS files
var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var link  = document.createElement('link');
link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
link.type = 'text/css';
link.href = chrome.extension.getURL('test.css');
head.appendChild(link);

var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var link  = document.createElement('link');
link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
link.type = 'text/css';
link.href = chrome.extension.getURL('jquery-ui.min.css');
head.appendChild(link);

// Injecting Jqueries
var s  = document.createElement('script');
s.src = "jquery.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);

var s  = document.createElement('script');
s.src = "jquery-ui.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
```

Comment: Thanks, this explains everything to me. I had no idea why I inserted in before <body> element....

Answer (score 2):

Usually this is fixed by adding `z-index: 9999999` CSS property to the positioned element (or a more reasonable number if you can control other element's z-order).

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your quick response. I swear I tried many values for z-index and with now it works even with values like 2. Anyway thanks !